# python looping with functions break and continue outside loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I am new to programming and so i'm practicing a bid. At this point i'm practicing with functions. In the code below break and continue are outside the loop i can not see why. I've tryed out different ways but the only thing i get to work is the last block of code. Why are break and continue outside the loop here?
    import random

```
again = 'y'

while again == "y" :
    def main():
        print "gues a number between 0 - 10."
        nummer = random.randint(1,10)
        found = False

        while not found:
            usergues = input("your gues?")
            if usergues == nummer:
                print 'Your the man'
                found = True
            else:
                print 'to bad dude try again'

main()  
again = raw_input('would you like to play again press y to play again   press n yo exit')
if again == 'n':
    break   #here it says it is outside the loop 
elif again != 'y':
    print 'oeps i don\'t know what you mean plz enter y to play again or n to exit'
else:
continue        #this is outside loop as well

#main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are new to programming, I will get a few basic tips in my answer too.

**INFINITE LOOP**

You are trying to start an infinite loop by first setting`again = 'y'` and afterwards you are using this variable to evaluate a while loop. Because you are not changing the value of y, it is better to not use a variable to create this infinite loop. Instead, try this:

```
while True:
    (some code)
```

**DEFINE FUNCTION IN LOOP**

You're defining the function `main()` inside of the while loop. As far as I can tell, there is no use for that. Just leave out the first while loop. If you define a function, it is permanent (much like a variable), so no need to redefine it everytime. Using your code, you won't even get to call the function, because you never end the first loop.

**CONTINUE/BREAK NOT IN LOOP**

The error is quite self-explanaitory, but here we go. If you would ever end the first loop (which in this case, you won't), the next thing you do is call your function `main()`. This will generate a number and make the user guess it until he got it right. When that happens, you get out of that function (and loop).

Next, you ask if the user would like to play again. This is just an input statement. You store the answer in the variable 'again'. You check, with an if statement *(note that this is not a loop!)* what the answer is. You want the user to play again if he typed 'y', so instead of using `again != 'y'`, you could use the following:

```
if again == 'y':
    main()  # you call the function to play again
```

If 'n' was typed in, you want to exit the script, which you do not by typing `break`, because you are not in a loop, just in an if-statement. You can either type nothing, which will just go out of the if-statement. Because there is nothing after the if, you will exit the script. You could also use`exit()`, which will immediately exit the script.

Lastly, you want to repeat the question if neither of these two things were answered. You can put the if-statement inside of a loop. You can (if you want) use your break and continue when doing this, but you mostly want to avoid those two. Here is an example:

```
while True:
    again = raw_imput('y for again or n to stop')
    if again == 'y':
        main()
        exit()  # use this if you don't want to ask to play again after the 2nd game
    elif again == 'n':
        print('bye!')
        exit()
    # no need for an 'else' this way
    # every exit() can be replaced by a 'break' if you really want to
```

**BASIC BREAK/CONTINUE USAGE**

Finally, here is some basic usage of `break` and `continue`. People generally tend to avoid them, but it's nice to know what they do.

Using `break` will exit the most inner loop you are currently in, but you can only use it inside of a loop, obviously (for-loops or while-loops).

Using `continue` will **immediately** restart the most inner loop you are currently in, regardless of what code comes next. Also, only usable inside of a loop.

**EVERYTHING TOGETHER**

```
import random
again = 'y'


def main():
    print ("gues a number between 0 - 10.")
    nummer = random.randint(1,10)
    found = False
    while not found:
        usergues = input("your gues?")
        if usergues == nummer:
            print ('Your the man')
            found = True
    else:
        print ('to bad dude try again')

main()
while True:
    again = input('would you like to play again press y to play again   press n yo exit')
    if again == 'n':
        print ('bye!')
        exit()  # you could use break here too
    elif again == 'y':
        main()
        exit()  # you can remove this if you want to keep asking after every game
    else:
        print ('oeps i don\'t know what you mean plz enter y to play again or n to exit')
```

I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to instructional material because you seem to misunderstand the general purpose of functions and the order of your logic.
Your function should be at the outer scope, e.g.:

```
def main():
    again = 'y'
    while again == "y" :
```

Your question for again needs to be indented into the while loop:

```
while again == "y":
    [snip]
    again = raw_input('would you like to play again press y to play again press n to exit')
    if again == 'n':
        break   #here it says it is outside the loop 
    elif again != 'y':
        print 'oops i don\'t know what you mean plz enter y to play again or n to exit'
    else:
        continue        #this is outside loop as well
```

The `else: continue` is unnecessary because you are at the end of the loop.
However, this only asks the question once, and you probably want this in a while loop. You also don't need to check the `again == "y"` in the outer while loop, because you are controlling the flow here:

```
    while True:
        [snip]
        again = raw_input("would you like to play again press y to play again press n to exit")
        while again not in ('y', 'n'):
            again = raw_input("oops i don't know what you mean plz enter y to play again or n to exit")
        if again == 'n':
            break
```

I would recommend against using a bare `input()` because any code could be executed, receiving a string and casting to an `int` would be safe (and you probably do some error checking):

```
usergues = int(raw_input("your guess?"))
```

Putting it all together it looks like:

```
def main():
    while True:    
        print "guess a number between 1 - 10."
        nummer = random.randint(1,10)

        found = False
        while not found:
            usergues = int(raw_input("your guess?"))
            if usergues == nummer:
                print 'You're the man'
                found = True
            else:
                print 'Too bad dude try again'

        again = raw_input('would you like to play again press y to play again press n to exit')
        while again not in ('y', 'n'):
            again = raw_input('oops i don\'t know what you mean plz enter y to play again or n to exit')
        if again == 'n':
            break

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You loops and `def` are all muddled, you want something more like:

```
import random

again = 'y'

while again == "y" :
    print "gues a number between 0 - 10."
    nummer = random.randint(1,10)
    found = False

    while not found:
        usergues = input("your gues?")
        if usergues == nummer:
            print 'Your the man'
            found = True
        else:
            print 'to bad dude try again'

    while True:
        again = raw_input('would you like to play again press y to play again   press n to exit')
        if again == 'n':
            break
        elif again != 'y':
            print 'oeps i don\'t know what you mean plz enter y to play again or n to exit'
        else:
            break
```